# jQuery mask appends question mark before last number

Tags: jquery, mask

I am trying to apply a mask in a phone input. My jQuery version is 1.11 and I am using Masked Input Js with the code below.

Despite that, the mask keep adding an question mark before the last number. What could be causing this?

```
  $.mask.definitions['~'] = "[+-]";
   
  $("#id_phone").focusout(function () {
    var phone, element;
    element = $(this);
    element.unmask();
    phone = element.val().replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (phone.length > 10) {
      element.mask("(99) 99999-999?9");
    } else {
      element.mask("(99) 9999-9999?9");
    }
  });
```

This is the result

[image]

Comment: There is a question mark in your mask pattern. ...what did you expect would happen?

Comment: Don't  the question mark makes the last number optional?

Comment: Is there a section in the documentation that says so? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show yours JS includes And html?
I made a phone mask using igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin, maybe it will help you:

```js
$(function(){
    $("#id_phone").on("change", function(){
        var phoneLength = 0;
        phoneLength = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g,"").length;
        console.log(phoneLength);
    if(phoneLength > 10){
        $(this).mask('(00) 00000-0000');
    }else{
        $(this).mask('(00) 0000-00000');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>


<div class="control-group">
  <input type="text" name="phone" id="id_phone" value="" />
</div>
```